# Finding out the x and y value of each Tile in a layer in Tiled

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skscene, tiled

So i am using a Tiled Map in Sprite Kit and i want to place tile on a new layer "enemy" so i can place where all the enemy's will start on the map.

This is a platform based game i am developing,

I was wondering if this was easy to do or if there are any good tutorials on this as i have had a look but can not find an.

i was thinking something like

```
for (CGPoint *tile in self.enemy)
{
//place enamy
}
```

Ben

Comment: Looks like you're off to a fine start.

Comment: If you are having a lot of issues with doing this I might suggest checking out a framework by the sprite kit alliance.  https://github.com/SpriteKitAlliance/SKATiledMap  it might help you out!